# Replicating Style of Copy/Paste Pop-out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

How would I replicate the style of the Copy/Paste pop-out so I could put custom buttons inside it.
I don't think it's a public class so how else would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.
Check out [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) and [UIMenuItem](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMenuItem_Class/Reference/MenuItem.html).

If you need more help, watch this Youtube Video for a tutorial.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1-Ty0FvFK0

Answer (score 2):

Just instantiate a view in the desired size, add a UIImageView with the backround image on it and add your buttons

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aRect];
UIImageView *bgView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:thePath]];
[overlayView addSubview:bgView];
[overayView addSubview:aButton];
[aButton release];
[bgView release];
```

*untested*

This code could be executed by a [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)